# Profiling spring application running on JBOSS EAP 6 using tool

Tags: spring, profiling, jboss6.x, spring-insight

We need to profile spring based web application running on JBOSS EAP 6 using some tool similar to Spring Insight.

Spring Insight help developers to understand and visualize the behavior of web application, however it doesn't support JBOSS EAP 6.

Comment: What about general purpose profilers like JProfiler or YourKit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe AppDynamics (http://www.appdynamics.com/) could be an alternative for you guys.